# Python : How to check whether the keys in the dictionary are substring of another key and thus sum the values?

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose we have the following dict:

```py
d = {'Alison Jane' : 20, 'Jane' : 10, 'Derek' : 44 , 'Derek Lee' : 20, 'Robert Dawson' : 5}
```

Now in the above dictionary the keys are names and the values are the counts,(frequency of the names appearing in any given text based data).

Now we know Alison Jane and Jane belong to same name thus instead of two of them showing separate counts I would like to have a summed up value, thus the total counts for Alison Jane becomes 20 + 10 = 30. Therefore the new dictionary becomes:

```
d_new = {'Alison Jane' : 30,'Derek Lee' : 64 ,'Robert Dawson' : 5'}
```

So I would like to know how do we proceed for the above?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Typically, it is appreciated when askers provide some details on what they have attempted themselves to solve or research the problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Write your code in code format..

Comment: Jane and Alison Jane have the last name in common, while Derek Lee and Derek the first? What if there were a Derek, Derek Lee, and John Derek? The problem is a bit confusing not knowing exactly the use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
print({k : sum([val for key, val in d.items() if key in k]) for k in [i for i in d if len(i.split(" ")) > 1]})
```

It will output:

```
{'Alison Jane': 30, 'Derek Lee': 64, 'Robert Dawson': 5}
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! It was a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```py
d = {'Alison Jane': 20, 'Jane': 10, 'Derek': 44, 'Derek Lee': 20, 'Robert Dawson': 5}

print({k: sum([d[x] for x in d if x in k]) for k in d if len([k for m in d if k in m]) == 1})
```

Output:

```
{'Alison Jane': 30, 'Derek Lee': 64, 'Robert Dawson': 5}
```